# Transfer of odor molecules from oil to water

Tags: solubility, aromatic-compounds

I brew beer, I'm not a chemist.  I want to add natural peanut aroma to a beer.  The most common way this is being done by brewers is the addition of peanut powder, which is essentially the product left over after pressing most of the oil out of roasted peanuts.  This product is preferable in brewing to whole peanuts because the introduction of significant amounts of oil into beer will affect desirable characteristics like the "head retention".

I don't like the idea of using this powder for various reasons. First, odor molecules like to be in oil, so pressing out the oil means pressing out a lot of the aroma.  Second, by adding all that powder to the beer, the beer ends up with far too much body and the powder absorbs some of the beer which lowers the yield.

If you've ever tasted roasted peanut oil, you'd notice that it is intensely flavorful of roasted peanuts.  What I'd like to do is extract odor molecules from the peanut oil and ultimately get them dissolved into a water based solution (a.k.a. beer).  This is where I was looking for help/ideas.

I've mixed aromatic fats with ethanol/water solutions (like everclear) and I've found there to be a reasonable transfer of aroma into the ethanol/water. I don't see this working in this case though.  The amount of odor molecules transferred to the solution would be insufficient when used to flavor beer.  The alcohol content of the beer would end up too high by the time enough of the solution was added to get the desired aroma intensity.

Comment: In chemistry, the word "aromatic" refers to a property of the electronic structure - it is unrelated to whether a molecule has an odor. It seems like you used the word "aromatic" to refer to odor molecules. If that's really the case, you might want to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.  My experience is with beer, so beer with me.

Comment: According to this publication https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20866052, the molecules responsible for roasted peanut odor are not particularly hydrophobic. Maybe they are easily extracted to an aqueous environment?

Comment: I suppose I could just combine the roasted peanut oil and water in a stir plate and let it go for a while and do some tastings of the resulting water, resulting oil, and the original oil for comparison.